# Creating "expireAfterSeconds" option on an existing index

Tags: mongodb

I know that you can modify existing values if your index has already the `expireAfterSeconds` option. Can we update existing index and make it have `expireAfterSeconds` option? Can we avoid dropping existing index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not. You will need to drop and recreate the index.